# My angular 2 object is printed on console, but individual properties are not being printed from the template

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my template and component code

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="newJobCreated">
        <h3>Name: {{newJob.name}}</h3>
        <h3>Job: {{newJob.job}}</h3>
        <h3>ID: {{newJob.id}}</h3>
        <h3>Created At: {{newJob.createdAt}}</h3>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
export class StockSearch {
    employeeName:string;
    employeeJob:string;
    employeeData = new Object();
    newJob: Object;
    newJobCreated: boolean

    constructor(public stockService:StocksService) {
        this.newJobCreated = false
    }

    createJob(){
        this.employeeData = {
            "name" : this.employeeName,
            "job" : this.employeeJob
        }
        this.stockService.postJson('https://reqres.in/api/users',this.employeeData).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.newJob = data._body
                console.log(data)
                console.log(this.newJob)
                this.newJobCreated = true
            },
            (err) => console.log('Error!',err)

        )
    }
}
```

My console prints the object as such when I do console.log(this.newJob). Something like 
{"name":"Vinod ","job":"Gandhi","id":"4","createdAt":"2017-05-26T08:43:21.476Z"}

But if you look at my template, those individual values are not being printed out.

Please help.

Comment: Could it be that you are getting a string, as you seem to do `this.newJob = data._body`. Do `this.newJob = data.json()`

Comment: Can you provide a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the string value of your response when you are doing:

```
this.newJob = data._body
```

You should get the JSON instead, so fast, easy fix is:

```
this.newJob = data.json()
```

I would though use `map` as well in the service:

Service:

```
postJson(....) {
  return this.http.(...)
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

and then in component

```
.subscribe(data => {
   this.newJob = data;
   this.newJobCreated = true;
})
```